# How to use operator "in" with MDX in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, mdx

I'm building an ssrs report with this MDX query:

```
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY { ([KeyWords Dim].[Keywords].[Keyword].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Ad Dim].[Countries].[Countries].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Creative Dim].[Creatives].[Title].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS,
  [Measures].[Clicks] ON COLUMNS
FROM [CubeName]
WHERE ([Time Dim].[Day ID].&[20140701]:[Time Dim].[Day ID].&[20140701])
```

I want to add another where clause to get only result for specific countries, something like that:

Where [Getways Dim].[Countries].[Countries].ALLMEMBERS IN ([Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["Germany"],[Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["US"]...)

How to do the "IN" part?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MDX, you do not use `IN`, you specify a set. The easiest way to specify a set is to just a list of members on braces like this:

```
WHERE { 
       [Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["Germany"],
       [Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["US"]
      }
```

and to combine conditions on two different hierarchies like Time and country, you build a cross product like this (`*` is the cross product operator in MDX):

```
WHERE ([Time Dim].[Day ID].&[20140701]:[Time Dim].[Day ID].&[20140701])
      *
      { 
       [Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["Germany"],
       [Getways Dim].[Country].[Countries].&["US"]
      }
```